# Dockerized kong not able to redirect the request to django which is inside docker

Tags: django, docker, kong

am new to kong and i installed kong and django inside my docker.from kong am able to forward the request to other servers but it is giving "received an invalid response from upstream server " when am trying to test the django api
please help,
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to do a query with http header `X-Kong-Debug: 1` to get more info ?
Does django server correctly answer ?

Comment: yes tried with that also its giving same

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.